# Refresh catalog in rancher with API call

Tags: rancher, rancher-cli

I can not find api call to refresh catalog/repository in rancher with API call. Is this function implemented? Version of rancher is v2.6.7. I can do it with rancher cli, but cli is [not working](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/30095) for new apps, so we decided to use API calls.

Answer (score 0):

you can enable `view in api` option to view most resources through the API
[image: screenshot of 'view in api' through rancher UI]

If you do this for a catalog, you will see the norman / v3 api options. For catalogs, you have the refresh `action` which is what you're looking for. The curl call would look something like

```
curl -u "${CATTLE_ACCESS_KEY}:${CATTLE_SECRET_KEY}" \
-X POST \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
'https://${rancher_url}/v3/catalogs/system-library?action=refresh'
```

note that directly using the v3 api is not covered under rancher support, so use this at your own discretion.